# Do I need to perform cross_validation after GridSearchCV?

Tags: cross-validation, gridsearchcv

In my model development, I compared 5 different classification model then using hold-out method, then applying hyper-parameter tuning using GridSearchCV, fit the data then evaluate.

My question is do I need to perform cross_validation after GridSearchCV?

```
SVM_para = [{'C': [1,10,100,1000], 'kernel':['rbf'],'gamma':[0.5,0.1,0.01,0.001,0.0001]}]

SVM_gs = GridSearchCV(estimator = SVM, 
                      param_grid = SVM_para,                       
                       scoring = 'accuracy',
                       cv = 10,
                       n_jobs=-1)

SVM_grid_search = SVM_gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
SVM_best_accuracy = SVM_grid_search.best_score_
SVM_best_param = SVM_grid_search.best_params_
```

Comment: What could be a purpose of extra cross-validation? GridSearchCV already uses CV and returns all the info you may need down the road: best model, score, best params

Comment: I want to compare the model performance of hold-out method and hyperparameter tuning.